# Effective upload to backend?

Tags: javascript, file-upload, web, backend

Let's say I have a website with frontend and backend. The website allows users to upload some data ranging from hundreds of MB to GB. How do you effectively upload these data?

- The easiest way would be to upload it from client/browser to the frontend server. Then send it via API or something to the backend server which has connected data storage, where we'll save the data. This would, however, run really slow, because the upload will be twice as big.
- Another way that occured to me would be to send the data directly from javascript running inside the browser to the backend's API. This can be inappropriate when I don't want the backend/backend's API to be accessible to public. It's also not good for the architecture (if you have fe and be, you probably don't want to comunicate from client to be).

So, do you have any ideas? Or is there some kind of general way to do this effectively? Does it include CDNs? Or should I store the data in a database as base64 strings if it'd only be few hundreds of MB pre file? Thanks.

EDIT: I just thought of using a Amazon S3 for this. This raises similar question where is the upload to S3 going to happen. In browser (and reference to S3 object will be sent to FE and BE) or in FE (and reference will be saved in BE DB) or in BE? Which one of them and why?

Answer (score -1):

from your question i understood that you are allowing users to upload files ranging from MB to GB. In that case u need to save the files in a particular folder and save the reference to that folder in your backend database. This will be the effective way of storing large data. If you save the data in the backend then it will overload your backend unnecessarily.

Comment: My question is how to effectively upload the data, not how to effectively store them. The point is that if the frontend and backend are different servers, the upload is duplicated — first it's uploaded from client to frontend and then from there again whole file via network to the backend. The data of course need to be on the backend system.

Comment: if your data need to be only on the backend system then you can directly upload it to your backend server from the client browser. If you read the Amazon S3 API documentation then you will get it.

Comment: What if I don't want the backend server to be accessible from the whole internet? Not speaking of the fact that the "password" for access to the backend would be out there in browser. Maybe I could solve the second problem somehow (how?), but is this really the clean way how it's done? I mean, for example how does Google Drive upload files?

Comment: Another thing.. can you link to specific part of the S3 Documentation you meant? And I don't mean to discuss the way to upload data, but the design, the architecture of the whole system. How it's properly done.

Comment: Jakub - Did u figure out a solution?

Answer (score -1):

One of the option is to mount S3 bucket as local directory on your server (using [RioFS](https://github.com/skoobe/riofs) for example), and let your web application save uploaded files to that folder. Files will be sent to your S3 bucket in parallel.